# NoVarsDynamicScope.java:87:in `setValue': java.lang.NullPointerException when run 'jruby -S warble -T' with warbler 1.3.5 or 1.3.6 on Fedora 14

Tags: jruby, fedora, warbler

After successfully porting a mature jruby servlet project from Ubuntu 12.04 to Fedora 14, everything works up to the point of building the servlet.

```
jruby -S warble compiled
```

works fine, but then

```
jruby -S warble war
```

or even just:

```
jruby -S warble -T
```

yields:

```
NoVarsDynamicScope.java:87:in `setValue': java.lang.NullPointerException
    from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RescueBodyNode.java:108:in `interpret'
    from RescueNode.java:199:in `handleJavaException'
    from RescueNode.java:141:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
    from RescueNode.java:110:in `interpret'
    from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:169:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:191:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:302:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:144:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:153:in `callIter'
    from FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:169:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:191:in `call'
    from SuperCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from SuperCallSite.java:146:in `callBlock'
    from SuperCallSite.java:151:in `call'
    from SuperCallSite.java:107:in `callVarargs'
    from ZSuperNode.java:102:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:147:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:183:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:292:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:135:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:63:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RootNode.java:129:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:119:in `INTERPRET_ROOT'
    from Ruby.java:724:in `runInterpreter'
    from Ruby.java:2487:in `loadFile'
    from ExternalScript.java:66:in `load'
    from LoadService.java:270:in `load'
    from RubyKernel.java:1076:in `loadCommon'
    from RubyKernel.java:1058:in `load'
    from RubyKernel$s$0$1$load.gen:65535:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:211:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:207:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:312:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:169:in `call'
    from /usr/local/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/warble:23:in `__file__'
    from /usr/local/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/warble:-1:in `load'
    from Ruby.java:697:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:690:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:597:in `runNormally'
    from Ruby.java:446:in `runFromMain'
    from Main.java:369:in `doRunFromMain'
    from Main.java:258:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:224:in `run'
    from Main.java:208:in `run'
    from Main.java:188:in `main'
```

I'm running:

- jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (OpenJDK Server VM 1.6.0_20) [linux-i386-java]

on an i686 machine under Fedora 14.  The latest JRuby is not yet mature enough for this project - I've tried it.

I've already tried reinstalling warbler-1.3.5 and upgrading it to 1.3.6 and rebuilding it locally but I always get the same error.

I can find the same error dating back as far as 2 years in online searches but with no followup discussion and no solutions.  Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Dave

Comment: The null pointer exception does not occur when the step:

    jruby -S warble compiled

is removed from the rebuild script.  This step precompiled the sources into .class files.  Removing it shifted reliance instead onto the Ruby interpreter’s just-in-time compiler.  The null pointer exception would otherwise occur in:

    jruby -S warble war

which builds the servlet from the source files in the absence of precompiled .class files using the winstone-jenkins JVM.

Comment: After the servlet is launched, we get the (probably unrelated) warning:

    (unknown):0 warning: instance vars on non-persistent Java type
    Java::OrgJrubyRackServlet::ServletRackEnvironment
    (http://wiki.jruby.org/Persistence)

Comment: Tracing the call stack shown above through the source code we find that when the warbler gem is launched after precompiling the sources into .class files, it parses them in recursive descent through an abstract syntax tree (AST).  It eventually gets to a begin - rescue - end block and throws an exception when a local assignment is attempted from a variable that hasn’t been allocated.

Comment: The *jruby -S warble war* step, by contrast - in the absence of precompiled .class files - triggers the use (and download, if necessary) of the winstone-jenkins JVM, which doesn’t need to parse precompiled .class files since it can operate directly on the source code, deferring any JIT compilation and consequent exposure to null pointers until after the completion of certain initializations - initializations which, if well-tested and applied to well-tested source code we would expect to eliminate any runtime encounters with null pointers.

Comment: To explain why we saw the null pointer exception only after porting to Fedora and building the JRuby servlet for the first time, note the syntax error detected by the JVM’s preprocessor after the warning about instance variables on a non-persistent Java type:

    when /.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/     : @indent = 0
                              ^):

This is immediately recognizable from recent experience as pertaining to the Ruby version - Ruby 1.8.7 corresponding to JRuby 1.6.7.2 vs. Ruby 1.9.x corresponding to JRuby 1.7.x.

Comment: Comparing the output of *jruby --version*:

    jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.8.7-p357)...

to the output of *ruby --version*:

    ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)

suggests that a patch was applied to the ruby installation under Ubuntu Linux and needs to be reapplied under Fedora.  It is not yet clear that this will cure the syntax error but the patch shouldn’t have to be fixed by hand, since the source code is up to date with the SVN repository which is anchored in JRuby 1.6.7.2/Ruby 1.8.7 and worked fine under Ubuntu.

Comment: Patching ruby 1.8.7 from patch level 352 to 357 had no effect on these results.  Back to square one.  For now I'll defer the use of precompiled .class files, fix the type usage and syntax errors by hand and see how it goes.